# IIS 6 to IIS 8 Migration Errors after using Microsoft Web Deploy

Tags: iis, iis-6, iis-8, webdeploy

I have recently been trying to migrate some websites from a 2003 server with IIS 6 to a 2012 server with IIS 8 installed.  I am using Microsoft's Web Deploy tool and have been successful in copying a few web sites one at a time using the following command (changing the site identifier # for each site).
NOTE: The reason the mumbo jumbo with replacing the drive exists is because our new server has a different data drive on it, and MSDeploy didn't like that.  Could that be breaking things as well?

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/#,computername=SourceServerNameHere -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/# -replace:objectName=metaProperty,scopeAttributeName=name,scopeAttributeValue=Path,targetAttributeName=value,match="F:",replace="E:" -enableLink:appPoolExtension > migration.log
```

The main issue is that when I try to navigate to any site one of three errors happens..
  1. 503 Service Unavailable
  2. 401.2 Unauthorized
  3. 404.17 Not Found

These errors start from 1, and progress to 3 as I am trying to troubleshoot the IIS configurations.  But this kind of defeats the purpose of using the Web Deploy Tool.  Has anyone had any luck migrating sites being completely successful, or does the tool not actually support "IIS 6.0 or higher migration?"

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So I have been able to get the main page of my site working by reverting the Handler Mappings and Default Documents to their parent configurations, and making sure that the AppPools don't conflict with versions, etc.  The problem with this, is that I have to figure out how to do this for every app and app pool under the sites...  Does anyone else have a similar problem?

Comment: Have you also tried using the iisApp Provider?

Comment: I have not. Is iisApp provider an alternative to using -replace?  Other forums directed me to using -replace when I initially ran into the issue of moving drives during the migration.

Comment: You have to manually fix the configuration after sync, as the drives differ. Web Deploy is designed to cover the simplest cases, and that keeps it simple and easy to maintain.

Comment: What configuration do I need to go fix? The IIS config file, web.config files or both? And are there just values in there looking for the old drive still?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up contacting Microsoft Support to get this sorted out and ended up spending 3 hours on the phone with them...There were multiple issues that came up during the deploy tool's migration.

The bulk of the issues were corrected by changing the application pools to 64-bit and commenting out abomappercustom handlers in the applicationhost.config.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the iisApp provider instead of the MetaKey provider.  For example,

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:iisApp=Site1/ContosoApp,computerName=Server1 -dest:iisApp="Site1/ContosoApp",computerName=Server2
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569054(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I have multiple websites with a bunch of web apps underneath that need to be migrated.  iisApp requires me to manually create a site on the destination server for every site I want to transfer, and then run the command.  Am I reading that correctly? 

**"In a sync operation, the iisApp provider copies content to a folder under the destination site that you designate and marks the destination folder as an application. The iisApp provider cannot create a site. The iisApp provider will not create applications under sites that do not exist."**